# Problem with wp_create_category

Tags: categories

I have simple code:

```
add_action('init', 'categoryTransfer');

function categoryTransfer(){
//some code
    for($i=0; $i < count($categories); $i++)
        wp_create_category($categories[$i]->name);
}
```

But when it executes i get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_create_category() in /Users/noname/Sites/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/my_plugin.php on line 95
```

Where is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is declared in `wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php`.
This file will be loaded in `wp-admin/includes/admin.php`.
And that now is called in `wp-admin/admin.php`.

So the solution is: Use the hook `'admin_init'` or require all necessary files manually. But don’t do that on every request.